# Form validation error. Redirects to error page

Tags: javascript, html, css

so I've created a form. I'm trying to use JavaScript to validate fields. When I press submit, it does nothing. It just sends me to a page saying 'Your file was not found.' I do realize that the code is mostly HTML and not JS. I've been testing as I'm going and it's not working already. Any help is appreciated

Here is my code:

```js
    
function validateForm() {
     
var firstname = document.myForm.fname.value;
if (firstname === "" || firstname === " ") {
 alert("First name is empty!");
 return false;
}
      
var middlename = document.myForm.middle.value;
 if (middle == "" || middle == " ") {
    alert("Middle name is empty");
    return false;
 }
      
      
}
    
function validateForm() {
     
 var firstname = document.myForm.fname.value;
 if (firstname === "" || firstname === " ") {
  alert("First name is empty!");
       return false;
  }
      
  var middlename = document.myForm.middle.value;
  if (middle == "" || middle == " ") {
     alert("Middle name is empty");
     return false;
     }
      
  var lastname = document.myForm.lname.value;
  if (lastname == "" || lastname == " ") {
  alert("Last name is empty");
  return false;
  }
 }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

     <head>
      <title>My form validation</title>
  
    
 </head>

  <body>
  
   <form name="myForm" action="fakeFormCheck.php" onsubmit="validateForm()" method="post">
    <fieldset>
     *First Name:
     <input type="text" name="fname">
     <br><br>
     
     Middle/Initial:
     <input type="text" name="middle">
     <br><br>
     
     *Last Name: 
     <input type="text" name="lname">
     <br><br>
     
     *Email: 
     <input type="text" name="email">
     <br><br>
     
     Phone:
     <input type="number" name="number">
     <br><br>
    </fieldset> 
    <br>
    
    <fieldset>
     *Reason:
     <select name="choice">
      <option value="Information">Infor reques</option>
      <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
     </select>
     <br><br>
     
     *Message: <br>
      <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30">
      </textarea>
    
    </fieldset>
    
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
    <input type="reset" value="Clear">
    
  
  
   </form>
   
  </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `preventDefault()` to the `validateForm` function & return `true` once the form is valid

```js
function validateForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var firstname = document.myForm.fname.value;
  if (firstname === "" || firstname === " ") {
    alert("First name is empty!");
    return false;
  }

  var middlename = document.myForm.middle.value;
  if (middlename == "" || middlename == " ") {
    alert("Middle name is empty");
    return false;
  }


}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" action="fakeFormCheck.php" onsubmit="validateForm(event)" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    *First Name:
    <input type="text" name="fname">
    <br><br> Middle/Initial:
    <input type="text" name="middle">
    <br><br> *Last Name:
    <input type="text" name="lname">
    <br><br> *Email:
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <br><br> Phone:
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <br><br>
  </fieldset>
  <br>

  <fieldset>
    *Reason:
    <select name="choice">
                    <option value="Information">Infor reques</option>
                    <option value="feedback">Feedback</option>
                    <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
    <br><br> *Message: <br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30">
                    </textarea>

  </fieldset>

  <input type="submit" value="Send">
  <input type="reset" value="Clear">



</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching the handler in Javascript rather than inline-eval-HTML, and using `preventDefault` to prevent the default form submission.

```
<form name="myForm" action="fakeFormCheck.php" method="post">
```

and

```
document.querySelector('form[name="myForm"]').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  // do tests
  if (invalid) {
    // something is invalid, prevent the default action of submitting the form:
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  // else the form will submit by default
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use return in `onsubmit="validateForm()"`  for example `onsubmit="return validateForm()"`.  second thing you are taking the middle name in `middlename` variable but your checking with some other varible `if (middle == "" || middle == " ") {`